# Problems with resizing window

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem is when i resize the window(smaller) One of my divs just go through and on top of my navigation bar... Which is annoying, but i believe there is a easy way to fix it. I can give you the code, but should test it in your editor program - and then resize, youll see what i mean.

HTML CODE HERE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="WorkFieldStartpage.css"/>


 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="upperblock">


     </div>

  <div class="topbar"></div>  



  <div id="pageContainer">

   <div id="pageContainer2">


            <div>
                <div id="leftnavigation">
                    <ul>
                    <li> <h4> Navigation </h4> </li>    
                    <li>Test text</li>
                    <li>Test text</li>
                    <li>Test text</li>

                    </ul>


                    </div>
                <div id="mainContainer">

                    <div id="newsfeed"></div>



                </div>

            </div>
       </div>
      </div>     

      </body>
      </html>
```

CSS CODE HERE:

```
 body {
 color: #333;
 line-height: 1.28;
 text-align: left;
 direction: ltr;

 }

 div {
 display: block;   



 }



 .topbar {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #11BD83;
 height: px;
 width: 100%;
 position:fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;

 }


 #pageContainer {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  min-height: 600px;
   }

  #pageContainer2 {
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;



  }

  ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  }

  h4 {
  text-decoration:underline;



  }





 #mainContainer {
 display: block;
 width: 620px;    
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 min-height: 800px;
 margin-left: auto ;
 margin-right: auto ;
 margin-top: 58px;   
 }

 #leftnavigation {
 float: left;
 height: 300px;
 width: 120.5px;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 display:block;




 }
```

Comment: Which div is busting the layout? Please specify

Comment: When im resizing, its the #mainContainer(the two grey lines) that just kinda through my navigation bar(#leftnavigation)

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary white space from your question's code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick look at your CSS I can see that in the `.topbar` class you have `height: px;` which means you are not assigning a height to that container. If you set the height to any number less than 58px (from what I tested) the containers shouldn't spill over into your gray vertical lines.

Comment: Hey man, thanks. I see they're not going through now. But now a new problem occured. Now when the grey lines(mainContainer) gets over to the navbar, it pushes the navbar upwards :O Is there a way i could do, so they just cant get any closer to eachother?

Comment: What browser are you using and what version number?

Comment: Also if you dont want your topbar to run over into the gray lines remove the position:fixed; from the .topbar class.

Answer (score 0):

normalize.css will sort out any browser default margins that could lead to problems.